# Django - after login, redirect user to his custom page --> mysite.com/username

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

By default after login django redirects the user to an accounts/profile page or if you edit the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) you can send the user to another page you specify in the `settings.py`.

This is great but I would like the user (after login) to be redirected to a custom page where the link to that page would look something like this: `mysite.com/username`. So, the default accounts/profile or the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` settings would not work in this case since both are somehow static. In my case the `username` section of the address changes for every user.

Any ideas how I can make it so when the user is logged in would go to a custom user page that has user's name in the address like:  `mysite.com/username`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can authenticate and log the user in as stated here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

This will give you access to the User object from which you can get the username and then do a HttpResponseRedirect to the custom URL.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using the django.contrib.auth.views that comes with django. Can I have the custom url described above in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can customize `auth.views.login` to that extent. That said, I would just write my own login function, exactly like the one in the documentation that I linked to above.

Answer (score 101):

A simpler approach relies on redirection from the page [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url).  The key thing to realize is that the user information is automatically included in the request.

Suppose:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profiles/home'
```

and you have configured a urlpattern:

```
(r'^profiles/home', home),
```

Then, all you need to write for the view `home()` is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
               reverse(NAME_OF_PROFILE_VIEW, 
                       args=[request.user.username]))
```

where `NAME_OF_PROFILE_VIEW` is the name of the callback that you are using.  With django-profiles, `NAME_OF_PROFILE_VIEW` can be 'profiles_profile_detail'.

Comment: How about for class-based views?

Comment: @User the `home` view can redirect to any url pattern, it doesn't matter whether it uses a function based view or a class based view.

Comment: The only issue with this (which may not be an issue for you) is that if there is a ?next=/someurl/ specified in the get for the login, you will never make it to the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL so the only way to guarantee they end up at the URL you want is to implement your own view.

Answer (score 14):

Yes! In your settings.py define the following

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/your-path'
```

And have '/your-path' be a simple View that looks up `self.request.user` and does whatever logic it needs to return a `HttpResponseRedirect` object.

A better way might be to define a simple URL like `'/simple'` that does the lookup logic there. The URL looks more beautiful, saves you some work, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Django's built-in `LoginView`, it takes `next` as context, which is "The URL to redirect to after successful `login`. This may contain a query string, too." (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView))

Also from the docs:

"If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in `next`. If next isn’t provided, it redirects to `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` (which defaults to /accounts/profile/)."

Example code:

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from account.forms import LoginForm # optional form to pass to view


urlpatterns = [
    ...

    # --------------- login url/view -------------------
    path('account/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='login.html',  
        authentication_form=LoginForm, 
        extra_context={ 

            # option 1: provide full path
            'next': '/account/my_custom_url/', 

            # option 2: just provide the name of the url
            # 'next': 'custom_url_name',  
        },
    ), name='login'),

    ...
]
```

`login.html`

```
...

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">

  ...

  {# option 1 #}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">

  {# option 2 #}
  {# <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url next %}"> #}

</form>
```

Comment: By Default any view that redirects to login will hold next variable. In case user logs in to login url directly then there is no next and system will  default to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. Just in case you need to specifically handle it as advised `extra_context={"next":mysite.com/username}` will resolve the requirement.

Comment: Tested with Django 2.2.5 and you need to specify also: redirect_authenticated_user=True in extra_context dictionary in order for this solution to work.

Comment: @cristian I believe `redirect_authenticated_user` is a separate parameter to the `as_view` function (i.e. it doesn't go in `extra_context`) (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). It controls what happens if an already authenticated user visits the login page (redirect them somewhere as if they had just logged in, or just let them visit the page).

Answer (score 7):

When using Class based views, another option is to use the dispatch method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/

Example Code:

*Settings.py*

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

*views.py*

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class HomeView(View):
    model = models.User

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        elif some-logic:
            return redirect('some-page') #needs defined as valid url
        return super(HomeView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer the method @Stu and others mentioned, which is to create a new URL and a view for it, so that we can put the redirection logic there. It's easier and users can also type `example.com/profile` in their browser to get redirected to their profile at `example.com/profile/username/`.

But another way that doesn't require defining an additional URL, is to extend the `LoginView` and redirect using the URL name for the profile view.

Let's say we have two apps named `accounts` and `pages`, and we have defined the profile page in the `pages` app, something like this:

```python
# pages/views.py
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        return HttpResponse('Hello ' + username + '!')
```

and the URLConf:

```python
# pages/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileView

app_name = 'pages'
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<str:username>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
]
```

Note that we must define `app_name = 'pages'` as we'll need it to refer to the URLs for the `pages` app.

Then, in the `accounts` app, we extend the `LoginView` and add the redirection logic:

```python
# accounts/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.urls import reverse

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.success_url_kwargs = {'username': form.cleaned_data['username']}
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # 'pages:profile' refers to the 'profile' path in the 'pages' app.
        return reverse('pages:profile', kwargs=self.success_url_kwargs)
```

```python
# accounts/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import CustomLoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

After a successful login, the `form_valid()` method gets called, and we add the parameters we want to use in the profile URL to the custom class attribute `success_url_kwargs`. Finally, calling `return super().form_valid(form)` first logs the user in, and then redirects to the URL given by the `get_success_url()` method (see the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/views.py)), which we define to return the custom URL we want.

Note that we included the URLs for the `auth` app after our custom login URL, so that the first one is resolved when we want to access `accounts/login/`.

Also, if we needed to access the user model instance, we can call `form.get_user()`. This can be useful in certain cases. For example, if the user logs in with email and we need his username, we can do `form.get_user().username`.

Answer (score 0):

Got into django recently and been looking into a solution to that and found a method that might be useful.

So for example, if using allouth the default redirect is accounts/profile.
Make a view that solely redirects to a location of choice using the username field like so:

```
def profile(request):
    name=request.user.username
    return redirect('-----choose where-----' + name + '/')
```

Then create a view that captures it in one of your apps, for example:

```
def profile(request, name):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=name)
    return render(request, 'myproject/user.html', {'profile': user})
```

Where the urlpatterns capture would look like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<name>.+)/$', views.profile, name='user')
```

Works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if redirect_field_value == None %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="/LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL(instead of typing in settings.py file)/">
{% else %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{redirect_field_value}}">
{% endif %}
```

Place this code in the login html page. For Example if you are directly accessing the login page (Example: /accounts/login/) then the 'next' value will be None that is after login its doesnot know to which page you have to redirect until you specify 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' in the settings page (Example: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL=/dashboard/). If you specify 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' in settings page as example shown then after login it will redirect to '/dashboard/' url.

If you need to access another url which also required login to view (For Example: /items/). So when you access 'localhost:8000/items/' as it required login to view it will redirect to 'localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/items/'. Here the value of 'next' will be 'items' but the problem is as you specified 'LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL' in settings page it always redirect to /dashboard/ url after login.

So the above html code helps to redirects if 'next' value is None then it will go to page that we specified as value for the hidden input. if 'next' is not None then it will redirects based on the value of 'next'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –