# having 2 groups of users to view 2 different views in django

Tags: python, django

i have a django project that has 2 types of users ( teachers and students in my case )

i want each group of them to view a different page when they login.
how is that possible ?

or how to know what group a certain user belong to  ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the groups of a user check the docs on [authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#methods).

> User objects have two many-to-many
>   fields: models.User. groups and
>   user_permissions. User objects can
>   access their related objects in the
>   same way as any other Django model:

```
myuser.groups = [group_list]
```

So if you want to check if a user is member of the group *teachers*:

```
if myuser.groups.filter(name='teachers'):
    print "myuser is a teacher"
    ...
```

Considering the redirection see this answer: [Django - after login, redirect user to his custom page --> mysite.com/username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username/4870674#4870674)