# Django Creating custom URL for user profile

Tags: django

I have an app which allows users to create a profile and log in.

When a user login , he is redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/

The problem is , I want to customize the URL by adding the user's username to the end of URL e.g example 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/michael

This is a similar question to mine

[Django - after login, redirect user to his custom page --> mysite.com/username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username)

*"get the username and then do a HttpResponseRedirect to the custom URL."*

I just can't seem to figure out how could I pass a username as an argument for HttpResponseRedirect to process into a the custom URL properly.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/?username=%s' % (username, request.path))


def Profile(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'person':person})
```

my URL

```
url(
    r'^profile/$',
    'pet.views.Profile',
    name = 'Profile'
),
```

NEW

my views.py

```
 def LoginRequest(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
        username = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        url = reverse('Profile', kwargs = {'username': username.username})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)        
if request.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        Person = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if Person is not None:
            login(request, Person)
            username= User.objects.get(username=request.user)

                            url = reverse('Profile', kwargs = {'username': username.username})
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)


return render(request, 'login.html',{'form': LoginForm()})




url(
    r'^login/$',
    'pet.views.LoginRequest',
    name = 'LoginRequest'
),

url(
    r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$',
    'pet.views.Profile',
    name = 'Profile'
),


def Profile(request,username):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))
    board = Board.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    person = Person.objects.get(user__username=username)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'board':board ,'person':person})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the proper regex for your redirect URL, ie. don't modify the one you have.

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'pet.views.myprofileview', name="detail_profile")
```

And then to pass an argument to the redirect:

```
url = reverse('detail_profile', kwargs={'username': profile.firstname})
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This leads to also having to define a new view:

```
def myprofileview(request, username):
    person = Person.objects.get(user = request.user)
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'person':person})
```

This would eliminate two behaviours in one view, which I find to be very nice!

We do it this way because it's a string that `HttpResponseRedirect` accepts so we have to build it accordingly.

This will make a redirect to the `myprofileview` view and "style", if you could call it that, your url `/profile/michael/`.

Comment: You're formatting it wrong. You should also do this outside the return, it goes for better readability. 

`formatted_string = "/profile/?{0}={1}".format(username, request.path)` and then `return HttpResponseRedirect(formatted_string)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28145/discussion-between-limelights-and-donkeyboy72)

Answer (score 1):

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Profile', 
            kwargs={'username': request.user.username}))  

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            Person = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if Person is not None:
                login(request, Person)

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Profile', 
                    kwargs={'username': username})) 

    return render(request, 'login.html',{'form': LoginForm()})
```