# Django Redirect after Successful Login

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a requirement that whenever I login or attempt to request a view that has a login_decorator then the next page be a page where I am required to ask the user to select a business entity (irreespective of the original view requested).

Let's say that the page is `http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/business_unit`

To achieve this I configured the following in my settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/APP/business_unit_selector'
```

Now when i try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/range_list` 
the page goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/login?next=/APP/range_list` I was expecting that the next page after login be `/APP/business_unit`

but instead, the next page was `/APP/range_list`

The browser address bar has `http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/login?next=/APP/range_list`

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying in Django?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is used unly when `next` is unspecified. In your test request there is `next=/APP/range_list` - and that address is used to redirect user after login.

Probably the easiest and most effective solution is to make your own decorator, similar to `login_required` which redirects to `/APP/business_unit_selector&next=<redirect_url>` if unit is not selected, and apply it together with `login_required`. It is not the most efficient solution in terms of redirects number, but is quite clean, and doesn't mess up the login page.

You will also have to handle `next` parameter in your `business_unit_selector` view, if you like to achieve natural flow.

Your decorator should be something like

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.http import urlquote
import functools

def business_unit_required(view):
    @login_required  # probably you want to incorporate it here
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'selected_business_unit' in request.session:
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (
                reverse('business_unit_selector'),
                urlquote(request.get_full_path())))
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/login?next=/APP/range_list` is redirecting you to `range_list` after logging in, is because with `next=` you are overriding what is specified in your settings file, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/APP/business_unit_selector'`.

If I understand correctly you need to user to choose a business entity after logging in.

A couple solutions that come to mind are as follows:

1.) Don't use a separate forms for login and business entity. Instead combine them.

```
Username
Password
Business Entity
```

2.) You can also specify in your view if the user doesn't have a buisness entity ResponseRedirect("/APP/business_unit_selector")
[docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Corrected the post. When i try to access http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/range_list the page goes to http://127.0.0.1:8999/APP/login?next=/APP/range_list I was expecting that the next page after login be /APP/business_unit

Comment: Can you post the code for your view functions? I'm thinking that if I see that portion of the code I can get a better understanding of what's going on.