# How redirect login.html to chat.html page after successful logged in Django framework?

Tags: html, ajax, django, django-templates

I have used template/login.html for logging in, after successful logged in how to redirect the login.html page to chatwindow.html page (some other html) in Django framework.

So, do I need to redirect it from views.py file or from login.html?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django implements multiple ways to do this:

#### 1. [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

This is a global setting in your `settings.py`. It works for all login pages when `next=` parameter is not specified in login url (e.g. `example.com/login?next=/foo`).

#### 2. Use `next` parameter in the login URL

This is usually used to customize the login redirect for individual cases.

The common use-case is when you use [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. When a user tries to access a page which requires authentication, a user is then redirected to a login page with a `next=` parameter pointing to the current page. For example if the user went to `/secure/page`, then the login page will be something like `/login?next=/secure/page`. After the user will successfully authenticate, Django will redirect them back to the protected page.

#### 3. Use the hidden input `next` on the login page

Finally you can set the redirect path in the login form itself:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
    <input typy="hidden" name="next" value="/secure/page">
    ...
</form>
```

I would guess that first method might be the most appropriate in your case however keep in mind the other options if you will need them.