# login redirect using custom user backend django

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user to a success page after login, but I don't understand the bussiness behind redirect, my home page is the login form, like so

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
  url(r'^dashboard/$', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

The index view handles the remote auth via a REST call:

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Login()
        return render(request, template_name, {
            'form': form,
        })
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        credentials = {"username": request.POST.get('username', ''), 
                       "password": request.POST.get('password', '')}
        user_backend = CustomRemoteUserBackend()
        new_user = user_backend.authenticate(credentials=credentials)

        if new_user is not None:
            Login(request, new_user)
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            form = Login()
            return render(request, template_name, {
                'form': form,
            })

@login_required()
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

But when the user submits, the login page loads again with this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/dashboard/
```

Finally, I have this in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL = '/'
```

How can I redirect to the dashboard view?, I tried using the built-in view for login, but since I'm using a custom user backend I didn't know how to override the default login behavior.

Comment: Why not use `django.contrib.auth.login()` to log users in? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: The login part is fine, I'm struggling with the redirect.

Comment: Sure, but Django does have an authentication layer that will handle logging in and redirection for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username

Comment: Thanks, I'll try what they say on that answer!