# Customizing Login Redirect URL in Django

Tags: python, django

After the user logs in i want to redirect to the view ('profile:profile_view')

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile:profile_view'
```

I tried the above code but was not getting the result that i needed because iam passing slug into the url

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='view_profile'),
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092760/django-login-and-redirect-to-user-profile-page) i tried the following.

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_redirect'
```

urls.py

```
@login_required
def login_redirect(request):
    return redirect('profile:profile_view', pk=request.user.pk, name=request.user.username)
```

Now i do get the username in the terminal but how do i use the username for the following **'localhost:8000/username'**

views.py

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = "profile/profile_view.html"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'profile'
```

**What am i doing wrong here? is there a better way?**

Answer (score 0):

Your profile URL accepts only one parameter called `slug` but you're passing it two parameters called `pk` and `name`.

First, change your URL like so:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='view_profile'),
```

Now, correct the `login_redirect` view to make it look like this:

```
@login_required
def login_redirect(request):
    return redirect('profile:profile_view', username=request.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also come in login in **views.py** and check and after that  use **httpresponseredirect** to redirect user:
For examplele:

In  **urls.py** :

```
           From . Import views

           Url(r'$login/',  views.login,  name="login"),
           Url(r'$profile/', viesm.profile, name="profile"),
```

In **views.py**:

```
         From django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
         From django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
          Def login(request):
                  *** place to check if exist in your database***
                  If ***exist***:
                         User=request.post["username"]
                         Request.session["username"]=user
                         Return httpresponseredirect("../profile")
                  Else:
                         Return httpresponseredirect("../login")

        Def profile(request):
                If "user" in request.session:
                        Return render(request," **path to your template  ", { "username" : request.session["username"] })
                else:
                        Return httpresponseredirect("../login")
```

It should be better i think