# login_required decorator not redirecting to the following view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to render the specified template only when the admin got logged in so I used login_required decorator
but it is redirecting to admin rather than rendering and displaying the specified template

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin/')
def employeesignupview(request):
    return render(request,'todoapp/employeesignup.html')
```

Comment: You need to create another login page by redirecting to the page you want You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870619/django-after-login-redirect-user-to-his-custom-page-mysite-com-username) discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it redirects the user to `'/admin/'` the first time, it creates a query param(`next`) with the URL of your view(`employeesignupview`) to be able to navigate the user back after successful login. But to access `'/admin/'` URL, the user needs to be logged in. And because the user isn't logged in to access `'/admin/'` this page it redirects to the admin login page and overriding the existing next param to `/admin/` value and that's why after logging in the user is being redirected to the `/admin/` page. To make it work as you wish, simply replace `login_url` parameter value to this `'/admin/login/'`:

```
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Loginrequired means that you only want people login to have access to your page but here the page you are protecting is the signup page that's 
astonishing.

And one more thing the login_url redirect you to the url you pass in your case you put "/admin/" so the view will send you to the admin page if you are not login.

Comment: what if I want to render the specified template after successful login

Comment: You do this with redirect. To answer correctly your question I need to see you login view.